# "Pro Paket werden 500 Einheiten des Artikels geliefert" wie nennt man die "500"?

Tags: word-choice

Wie nennt man die "500", wenn man bspw. in einem Onlineshop einen Artikel nur einmal bestellen muss, um 500 Stück geliefert zu bekommen?

- Stückmenge?
- Einheitengröße?

Comment: Das nennt man "Anzahl".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich kenne hier den Begriff "Verpackungseinheit" (kurz: VPE) oder auch "Packungseinheit" (PE), wenn der Artikel üblicherweise zu beispielsweise 500 Stück in einem Karton verpackt ist und nur in "Verpackungseinheiten" abgegeben wird. Das wird beispielsweise beim Verkauf von Broschüren/Heften so gehandhabt.

Die "Stückzahl" ist eher eine Bezeichnung, wenn einzelne, separate Artikel gemeint sind. In Listen kommt es vor, dass die Mengenspalte als Stück oder Stückzahl bezeichnet wird, in der Artikelbeschreibung dann die Verpackungseinheit Karton oder Ähnliches aufgeführt ist: "3 Karton LaTeX Grundlagen" bedeutet 15 Stück "LaTeX Grundlagen", wenn in einem Karton 5 Stück verpackt sind.

Comment: Wikipedia nennt hier https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verpackungseinheit noch den Begriff *Verkaufseinheit*

Comment: Ja, aber es geht bei der Erwähnung um den Unterschied: Eine Verpackungseinheit fasst mehrere Verkaufseinheiten zusammen.

Answer (score 3):

Das nennt man Packungsgröße oder Losgröße.

Comment: Für mich ist das die beste Antwort, weil so eine Unterscheidung der bestellten "Einheiten" (Stückzahl) und der Anzahl pro Einheit (Packungsgröße) möglich ist.